# How to get image from another website with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I'm a volunteer for an association, and we would like people to be able to put a badge on their site to show their support.

To keep things easy to manage, I was thinking of giving them a javascript function to paste on their site, which would call an url on our site, retrieving the image and showing it.

Would it be the right way to do it ?

If so, can you give me an example of code for the page on our side ?

Thank you

Bruno

Comment: Are you just asking how to create an `img` tag?

Comment: why don't you give them the link to the image?

Comment: Because I would like to be able to change the image without having to send it again to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give them an image tag with a source that points to your server:

```
<img src="http://yourserver.com/image.jpg">
```

The user's browser will load the image from that source, regardless of what page/domain the user is on (as long as hotlinking and defenses against it are not an issue). No need for javascript.

Good luck!

Comment: If possible, please use protocol relative links. `//yourserver.com/image.jpg`

Comment: Actually, as I just wrote, I want to able to change the image loaded on every "supporter" site without having to send them anything.